# why do we use HttpContext.Current?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don't know, why do we use `HttpContext.Current`?
In this property I use it for `Session` but I don't know why!

```
public static string Name
{
    get
    {
         if (HttpContext.Current.Session["_n_"] != null)
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["_n_"].ToString();
         else return "";
    }
    set
    {
         HttpContext.Current.Session["_n_"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5060948/224370

Comment: We used HttpContext.Current for accessing session object in class

Comment: thanks it was useful to me :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`HttpContext` is an object that wraps all http related information into one place. `HttpContext.Current` is a context that has been created during the active request. Here is the list of some data that you can obtain from it.

1. Request type (Post, Get)
2. Request parameters (querystring, posted data)
3. User's IP address
4. Cookies

Further you can control your output through this object. In `Items` property, which is a dictionary, you can store instances of objects to ensure that they are created once for the request. You can control the output stream applying your custom filters.

This is a short list of that what you can do with this property.

Answer (score 4):

It's a way to get access to the current HttpContext someplace that may not have a reference to the context but is within an active web request.

Answer (score 4):

That's like saying "Why do I need to go to a bank to get money?", to which the answer is "Because that's where the money is.

To answer your question.  Because that's where the Session is.  It's really that simple.  You don't have to know why, just that that's where it is.

There's a much longer explanation, which other people are giving with all the technical details.  But in the end, the answer just boils down to this.

Answer (score 0):

before asp.net MVC in a web form, there were classes request, response where you can get cookies and session and those staff in MVC all the HTTP information like request and response and their properties are now inside HTTpcontext.

Comment: It hasn't changed. Under ASP.NET MVC are the same classes in the System.Web namespace. They are called HttpRequest, HttpResponse, ... and you can access the instances of the current request through the property HttpContext.Current like before. WebForms has properties in the Page class for this purpose, but HttpContext exists as well.

Comment: I didn't say that it changed I said the request and response classes are encapsulated inside Httpcontext,  but you 100% correct also ^^ as he can access the request directly from request property inside the controller